# Conducting Sphere with a charge inside

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

What happens if we put a charge inside a conducting sphere(not a shell)?

If we take a gaussian surface around the charge then we find that there should be charge at every radius of the sphere. But this can't happen since we know the charge inside a conductor is zero.

Do the charge inside the conducting sphere affect its potential?

(Note that the charge is not inside a cavity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described situation is impossible in electrostatics, since the central charge would induce a current in the metal, which will transfer charge until the central charge becomes completely compensated. As a result, we will see an ordinary charged sphere with a charge uniformly distributed over the external surface. The charge of the sphere will be equal to the initial value of the central charge.